# Creating a node that contains paragraphs / field collection / entity reference fields

Tags: 7, entities, services

The Services module is good for creating nodes via a REST API, but how can you create nodes that contains reference fields like paragraphs, field collections, or entity reference fields? I couldn't find any examples of someone doing this or a module that solves this problem.

What solutions are there to create nodes with reference fields using the Services module?

Comment: For entity reference fields you have to pass the Entity ID, not the title.

Comment: They’re just fields like any other field - what are you trying? What’s not working?